# Using querySelector to read 2 values from radio button

Tags: javascript, html

Hello how can i use the queryselector to read two values from a radio button and store the values in array in javascript. Example of the code below is:

```
                   <input type="radio" name="one" value="correct" class="firstRow">&nbsp;Option 1 Mark 1: $650
                    <input type="radio" name="two" value="incorrect" class="secondRow">&nbsp;Option 1 Mark 2: Twitter<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="one" value="incorrect" class="firstRow">&nbsp;Option 2 Mark 1:$550
                    <input type="radio" name="two" value="incorrect" class="secondRow">&nbsp;Option 2 Mark 2:Google<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="one" value="incorrect" class="firstRow">&nbsp;Option 3 Mark 1:$650
                    <input type="radio" name="two" value="correct" class="secondRow">&nbsp;Option 3 Mark 2:$650<br>
                  <!--button -->
                    <input type="button" value="Submit & Next Question" onclick="getAnswer3(this.form)" class="firstRow">
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel & Clear Selection" onclick="clearOptions(this.form)">
```

Javascript my idea:

```
function getAnswer3(form) {
   var result = [];
   //this only reads one value but i need to read 2 values..
   var checked = form.querySelector("input[type=radio]:checked");

   if(!checked) {
    alert('Please select 2 answers..');
}
  else{
       //reads the values 
    }
   //stores the values in the array..
}
```

Comment: Instead of `input[type=one]:checked` should be `input[type=radio]:checked`

Comment: @The yes updated the correction but it only takes one value not 2 values as i intended

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `form.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]:checked");`

Keep in mind that what comes back from `querySelectorAll` is not really an array, and so doesn't have any of the particularly fun and easy helper methods that typical arrays do.

It does have a length, though.

`if checked` is not going to be helpful, though.
You're always going to get a `NodeList` back.

The list might have length === 0, but it'll still be a list (and thus still pass the check to see if it exists). Check that length is < 2, instead.

Comment: whats the difference between "==" and "===" in javascript

Comment: @user3497437 Type coercion. `false == undefined;` `null == undefined;` `0 == undefined;` `'' == undefined;` versus `false !== undefined;` `null !== undefined;` `0 !== undefined;` `'' !== undefined;` Don't fear it, but understand why you'd want to use `===` instead of `==` in much of your code.